# Why do probabilists have a preoccupation with urns?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Why is there an off-putting amount of questions from probability or combinatorics that involve an urn? Is there some historical reason?

Did someone not have a box, or other container, on hand and had to bother their grandparent's remains to help solve a mathematical puzzle? Or did some author decide that one only draws balls from urns, and future authors kept repeating the same scenario ?

It has always just struck me as weird and thought maybe someone here knew.

Comment: Because when you "randomize" the balls by shaking the urn, there is less chance for ball spillage.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem#Historical_remarks

Comment: My grandparents never used urns, nor did their undertakers. On the other hand, probably was discovered eons before them.

Comment: @JonasMeyer although that helps, that just begs the question why English authors didn't translate _urna_ into a more general term.

Comment: "Urn" *is* a general term; it just means a large jar or vase.  It just so happens that one particular use for an urn is to hold human ashes.

Comment: Because urns are smooth and round objects, it is simple to create a model for how the balls roll inside them.

Comment: *Why do probabilists have a preoccupation with urns?* - Because they secretly plan on overthrowing the government by rigging the next election !

Comment: It strikes me as remarkably obtuse to demand an explanation for why Italian *urna* was translated as English "urn". An explanation might be required if *urna* had been translated as anything else.

Comment: @MJD that's a strikingly acute statement for a legitimate question. A similar question could be asked for why we say 'eigenvalue' instead of 'proper value' (which was the standard usage for a while). But we know why we say eigenvalue: we adopted the usage of Hilbert (or Helmholtz).

Comment: I feel that this is a legitimate question, and I have nominated it for re-opening. The notion of urns and balls is, in the modern era, quite disconnected from reality. Although mathematics need not be connected to an intuitive reality, basic probability is one of those fields with broad applicability, so the continued reliance on urns and balls may actually have a deleterious effect on the education of basic concepts, because it seems so worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

questions with balls and urns are members of a class of problems that became known as Urn problems, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem, which quotes Jacob Bernoulli himself and explains why he used the Latin word urna, also the present day Italian word for ballot box.

Comment: This does help, but it doesn't explain why _urna_ wasn't replaced by a less specialized term in mainstream English mathematics. I have seen 'ballot box' used, but 'urn' remains the popular term.

Comment: Both "box" and "bin", equally short as "urn", are often used, though perhaps the combinatorialist and probabalist preferences are statistically distinguishable.